# libGDX unlockables management and gdx-pay\Native Android\IOS payments

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx, payment

I want to implement unlockable characters that can be purchased and I have a few questions about the best way to implement this in my game.

Currently I manage unlockables by storing them as preferences.  However I'm now in the process of making them purchasable.

1. Is gdx-pay the best way to do this or create a native Android\iOS
   implementation?
2. Once a method of purchasing characters has been implemented and the
   user purchases one, what happens when the user uninstals my game?
   i.e. should I reverify purchases on startup? This will require an
   network connection, if the user doesn't have one it doesn't restore?
3. Should I be using preferences to store unlocked characters etc or
   another method?  My reason behind this method was to avoid having
   ship a database with it and having to create separate sqLite
   implementations for each platform.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point 1. Yes, for now if you want to go cross platform then gdx-pay is your choice. Recently they've also added support for IOS 9 which is great. You will be able to deploy on both Android and IOS with minimal change of code.

Point 2. You should always call requestPurchaseRestore in your splashScreen or somewhere on startUp to restore any purchases. This will ensure that even if the user uninstalls the game and installs it on another mobile device they will still have the purchases they've made. Of course, network connection is vital. If you don't have network access and you call requestPurchaseRestore you will get an error. That's why you should have a method to check if the user has access to the internet (wi-fi or mobile enabled) and only then call requestPurchaseRestore. If the user doesn't have internet they won't be able to restore Purchases. I don't see a problem with that. You can put a label somewhere that you need internet to restore purchases.

Point 3. Yes, having a local preferences file is a good idea. This is what I do myself. If an item is purchased you simply store it in the file. You may well use a db too but it's too much hassle for this kind of job.

Comment: Thanks. Its good to know other people use the preferences file and I'm not doing something complete off course and unmaintainable. For point 2 I'm considering putting the restore in the settings menu on a button as I read somewhere that for IOS a restore has to be requested by a user.  Is this definitely the case?

Comment: yes, the scenario I described with calling requestPurchaseRestore in the splash is only for android. For IOS you need to have a button and the user must explicitly request it